# Prolog recursively count numbers in a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I need a program to count all the numbers in a list, no matter how DEEPLY NESTED they are. I was able to count numbers in the case where they were not inside another list, but recursing through deeply nested elements is not working out. I have this so far:

```
count([],0).
count([H|Tail], N) :-
    count(Tail, N1),
    (  number(H)
    ->N is N1 + 1
    ;   is_list(H)
    -> count(H,N)  
    ;   N = N1
    ).
```

So, if I were to call `count([a,1,[2,b],3],N)`, the output should be `N=3`; however, I only get `N=2`. Could someone please help me add to my second case test? All available solutions here do not work for deeply nested numerical elements.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just flatten the list to begin with, then count the numbers from that?

Comment: No, I did try a solution with flatten, but it was "discouraged" since we are expected to use recursion for nested sub-lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect for the `is_list(H)` branch: in that case you ignore the value of `N1`, which is not correct, you want `N` to be the sum of `N1` with the count on `H`.

Complete code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

count([], 0).
count([H|T], N) :-
    count(T, N1),
    (   number(H) ->
        N #= N1 + 1
    ;   is_list(H) ->
        N #= N1 + N2,
        count(H, N2)
    ;   N1 = N
    ).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works with the module you have mentioned. However, I needed to do this without any external modules and wanted to replace the #= operator. I looked into clpfd module and realized that this operator is similar to the _is_ operator. However, we need the variable to be instantiated when we are using the _is_ operator. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @AbhishekRauniyar Replace `#=` with `is`, and swap the `N #= N1 + N2` line with the `count(H, N2)` line. (and remove the module obviously)

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!