# Prolog - Counting the amount of times a number appears in a list

Tags: prolog

So I am pretty much new to Prolog. I need to write a code segment that will count all the times any number appears in a list, no matter how deeply nested. For example, 
    countNums ([1, a, 2, [3, b, 4, [5, c, 6]]], N) 
should return N = 6

Here's my code:

```
listp([]).                        %define listp's
listp([H|T]).
countNums([],0).                    %base case for empty list
countNums([H|T], N) :- listp(H).    %check if head is a list
countNums([[H|T]|T1], N) :- countNums([H|T], N).
%check if head is not a number, if not do func with tail and dont increment
%if it is, do func with tail and increment N
countNums([H|T], N):- (
    number(H) ->
    countNums(T, N1),
    N is N1+1;
    countNums(T, N1),
    N is N1).
```

So, this code will work if the list is just a one level list (i.e. [1,2,3]), but if it encounters any new levels (i.e. [1,2,[3]]), it fails and exits.

I know a lot of this code probably doesn't make sense, but maybe you fine folks can help me out?

Comment: The exact same question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259887/prolog-recursively-count-numbers-in-a-list), just a day ago. Chances are you even are classmates…

Comment: @Fatalize: Just vote to close-as-dupe.

Comment: @false I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Fatalize: You do have [the priviledge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to flag-as-dupe. So not only the (current) [quaternity](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/tag-badges/prolog?badgeClass=Gold) can help to sort out questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
countNums([],0). %1
countNums([H|T],N) :- number(H), !, countNums(T,N1), N is N1 + 1. %2
countNums([[H|T1]|T2],N) :- !, countNums([H|T1],N1), countNums(T2,N2), N is N1 + N2. %3
countNums([_|T],N) :- countNums(T,N). %4
```

To break it down, predicate (1) is the base case for an empty list; predicate (2) matches on a list and, if the first goal of `number(H)` succeeds then we've found a number so there is no point in trying any of the other predicates so hence the cut (`!`); (3) matches when we have a list where the head of the list is also a list, and again, in this case, we don't want to try the remaining predicate, so we now recurse in to the head list and count the tail, and then add together both results; and finally we've hit the case with (4) that the head is neither a number nor a list so we just skip past the head and count the tail.

Then:

```
?- countNums([1, a, 2, [3, b, 4, [5, c, 6]]], N), write(N), nl, fail.
```

gives me this:

```
6
No.
```

One solution only and failure because of the `fail`.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Great code. Could you perhaps elaborate/comment on exactly what's happening in each step? If you don't have time to do all that, maybe at least these parts?: I don't understand what the '!' does; also, perhaps you could explain what's going on specifically in the 3rd line? If not, that's ok, I don't want to ask too much of anyone. Just wanted to learn what's happening exactly. As much information as you could provide would be incredibly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: @teddymv - Done.